# Importing PDF files to app

Tags: iphone, swift, share

I am trying to import a PDF file from other applications, such as mail, but I'm not sure exactly what I should be looking for. I want my user to be able to tap on the share button in a PDF and my app to be listed there as a place that can accept them, such as "Copy to iBooks"

Any good tutorials? Or suggestions as to what I should look for?

Preferably in Swift

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use Action Extension for making PDF available in your app

Below i have linked Some Tutorials for Action Extension which is not perfect for your requirement but you check the concept and basic implementation for it 
[Bookmark from Browser](http://www.appcoda.com/ios-8-action-extensions-tutorial/)
[Read a text](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ios-8-how-to-build-a-simple-action-extension--cms-22794)

[Official apple doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/Services.html)

Answer (score 1):

You can tell your app which types of documents it will support in the **info.plist**. A good place to start is [Registering the File Types Your App Supports](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/DocumentInteraction_TopicsForIOS/Articles/RegisteringtheFileTypesYourAppSupports.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010411-SW1)
in the iOS documentation.